# How to draw a line between radio buttons?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have been trying to apply the same design on the image below using HTML/CSS and that is what I have achieved so far.

[image]

```css
.slider{
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  li {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10rem;
    
  }
```

```html
<ul class="slider">
          <li class="slider-item">
            <label for="f-option">In Depth Knowledge</label>
            <input type="radio" id="f-option">
          </li>
          <li class="slider-item">
            <label for="g-option">Exellence & Education</label>
            <input type="radio" id="g-option">
          </li>
          <li class="slider-item">
            <label for="k-option">In Depth Knowledge</label>
            <input type="radio" id="k-option">
          </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: where is image?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! So far you don’t actually have a question. Thanks for providing your code, but we don’t know what it is you’re trying to achieve.

Comment: can't see what issue you are really facing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16Vhv3xQfJvd7ukVrT_RpQe5rsifyM5fG/view?usp=sharing
 here is the link to the image

Comment: find this example and apply this into your code : https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/components/stepper/

Comment: @MohitGupta Thanks!

Comment: @MohanadElhag see my answer below according your code(I made it responsive)

Answer (score 4):

Use code as below:

Using [`li{flex: 0 1 33%;}`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex/) and for line use `pseudo` as `:after`

[See fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1m3opk8x/)

**NOTE!**

If you want the user can select only one of the radio buttons use `name` attr

```css
    .slider {
      display: flex;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    label {
      width: 80px;
      display: block;
    }

    input {
      margin-left: 30px;
      margin-right: -1px;
    }

    li {
      flex: 0 1 33%;
      list-style: none;
      position: relative;
    }

    li:not(:last-child):after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      height: 1px;
      width: 100%;
      background: black;
      top: 45px;
    }
```

```html
<ul class="slider">
  <li class="slider-item">
    <label for="f-option">In Depth Knowledge</label>
    <input type="radio" id="f-option" name="rb">
  </li>
  <li class="slider-item">
    <label for="g-option">Exellence & Education</label>
    <input type="radio" id="g-option" name="rb">
  </li>
  <li class="slider-item">
    <label for="k-option">In Depth Knowledge</label>
    <input type="radio" id="k-option" name="rb">
  </li>
</ul>
```